# Access rights by cloning a Drupal sandbox repository

Tags: version-control

I try to clone a new Drupal sandbox project:

> git clone --branch 8.x-1.x username@git.drupal.org:sandbox/username/projectnumber.git directory

I receive the following error message:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I have the following configuration:

- Win8 (64bit)
- git 2.11.1 (it is the latest version)
- PowerShell / Git Shell / CygWin bash (all display the same error message)

The [Troubleshooting](https://www.drupal.org/node/1065850) does not address the issue.

---

I have tried several variants of the clone command. The following have worked:

```
git clone --branch 8.x-1.x https://username@git.drupal.org/sandbox/username/projectnumber.git directory
```

There are only two chages needed:

- **https://** before the username
- **/** instead of **:** before sandbox

But when I try 'git push', then i get the following error message:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://username@git.drupal.org/sandbox/username/projectnumber.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

If I edit the file .git/config and change the [remote "origin"] url to: **ssh**://username@git.drupal.org/sandbox/username/projectnumber.git, then I get the same error message as by the clone command:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

And if I test the SSH connection: 'ssh username@git.drupal.org', then I get the same error message:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

The error message is the same if I use [password or SSH key authentication](https://www.drupal.org/node/1027094).

---

@Jakuje [writes](https://serverfault.com/a/813545):

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

You can't establish SSH connection to the remote host for some reason. You are probably blacklisted using /etc/hosts.deny or the server is failing to accept the connections and initiate SSH protocol for other reasons (missing directories, disk failures, full disk, etc.). The logs from the server will tell you more.

Comment: This isn't likely to be a Drupal problem, see http://serverfault.com/questions/445045/ssh-connection-error-ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-pe for details

Comment: I deleted SSHD's HostKeys and tried everything, what I have found, but without success. I use SSH for a lot of other purposes without problems. And also git works by all other projects perfectly.

Comment: You shouldn't need to provide a username when accessing the http url. You only need to clone via ssh if you have a key configured on your drupal.org account.

Comment: @mradcliffe I suppose, that the key on my drupal.org account is configured correctly, because on my personal computer with Ubuntu work all the git commands perfectly. But the same commands produce on my office computer with win8 the above mentioned error messages.

Comment: @mradcliffe I have generated a new SSH key as described here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1066762, but I still receive the same error message.

Comment: I have found, that the error message can have the following reason: "You are probably blacklisted using /etc/hosts.deny on the server." It would mean, that the public IP of the company, where I work (91.208.212.1), is on git.drupal.org blacklisted. It would be funny, if it's really the case :-)